# How to get JSR-356 (javax.websockets.api) working on Jetty 9.3 JEE environment not embedded?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am having a hard time trying to get a simple echo server using javax.websockets on jetty 9.3 servlets (not embedded).

Server:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
import javax.websocket.MessageHandler;
import javax.websocket.RemoteEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.Session;


public class EchoServer extends Endpoint {

    @Override
    public void onOpen( Session session, EndpointConfig EndPointCfg ) {
        RemoteEndpoint.Basic remoteEndpointBasic = session.getBasicRemote();
        session.addMessageHandler( new EchoMessageHandler( remoteEndpointBasic ) );

    }

    private static class EchoMessageHandler implements MessageHandler.Whole<String> {

        private final RemoteEndpoint.Basic remoteEndpointBasic;


        private EchoMessageHandler( RemoteEndpoint.Basic remoteEndpointBasic ) {
            this.remoteEndpointBasic = remoteEndpointBasic;
        }


        @Override
        public void onMessage( String message ) {
            try {
                if ( remoteEndpointBasic != null ) {
                    remoteEndpointBasic.sendText( message );
                }
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.Endpoint;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerApplicationConfig;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;


public class EchoServerCfg implements ServerApplicationConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses( Set<Class<?>> set ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs( Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> set ) {
        Set<ServerEndpointConfig> result = new HashSet<ServerEndpointConfig>();
        if ( set.contains( EchoServer.class ) ) {
            result.add( ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create( EchoServer.class, "/websocket/echo" ).build() );
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

It works just fine on tomcat 7.0, but no luck on Jetty 9.3, any help will be appreciated.

---

**Edit 1:**
It's missing the information about the problem, I am getting 404 so I believe the endpoint does not get mapped:

```
$ wscat -c localhost:8080/websocket/echo 

error: Error: unexpected server response (404)
```

but it works fine on tomcat:

```
wscat -c localhost:8081/websocket/echo 

connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
> test

< test
```

---

**Edit 2:**

Java version:

```
tiago@lenovo:~$ /opt/jdk/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

I am using [eclipse-jetty plugin](http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/) to run, but here's my command in the shell:

```
tiago@lenovo:~$ ps axo cmd  | grep jetty  | sed -re 's/:|\s+/\n/g'
/opt/jdk/bin/java
-Djetty.launcher.configuration=/tmp/eclipseJettyPlugin.config.TestServlet.xml
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1011/1/.cp/lib/eclipse-jetty-starters-common.jar
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1011/1/.cp/lib/eclipse-jetty-starters-util.jar
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1011/1/.cp/lib/eclipse-jetty-starters-console.jar
/opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1011/1/.cp/lib/eclipse-jetty-starters-jetty9.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-servlets-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-jndi-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-annotations-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/annotations/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/annotations/asm-5.0.1.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-plus-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-proxy-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-infinispan-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-io-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-http-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-jmx-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-quickstart-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-deploy-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-jaas-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-client-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-security-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-util-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-nosql-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-alpn-server-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-continuation-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
/opt/jetty/lib/jetty-jaspi-9.3.3.v20150827.jar
net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.starter.jetty9.Jetty9LauncherMain
```

---

**Edit 3: [SOLVED]**

The problem was jetty-eclipse plugin, it turns out that their version 3.9.0 released yesterday 2015/10/11 solves the problem. Also deploying manually does the tricky but it's nice to use the plugin when using eclipse.

Comment: How did you start the server?  in other words, what is your `${jetty.base}` configuration? `$ cd /path/to/my/jetty.base ; java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No websocket implementation classes are present in your running server.

That's why there's no JSR356 support available to you.

Did you check off the option to enable websocket support?

> Note: Know that the 3rd party Eclipse Plugin you are using
>   (http://eclipse-jetty.github.io/) is not run, managed, maintained,
>   endorsed, recommended by any of the Eclipse Jetty developers.
>
> The Eclipse Jetty project has no official Eclipse Plugin.
>
> The Eclipse Jetty Project developers prefer instead that you use
>   Embedded Jetty facilities to develop/test while in any IDE (even
>   IntelliJ, NetBeans, vim, emacs, JEdit, etc..).

Comment: Oh man you're awesome! deployed manually and it all worked! thanks alot!

Comment: Hey @Joakim, trying to find the classpath for jetty... it does not use `-cp` nor environment `$CLASSPATH`, how does jars get loaded?

Comment: That would likely be something that the specific plugin you are using is configuring.   If you are talking about the jetty distribution, then the `start.jar` manages all of that.  See [the official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html) for more.

Comment: From the docs `The start.jar bootstrap builds a classpath`, how does that work? can you point some docs about it?  another question  since I have no -cp and no $CLASSPATH how can I check which jars are being loaded once the server is started?

Comment: The docs tell you, so does the `--help` for the `start.jar`, you can use the technique in the comments underneath your question, and even use built-in dump features of the Server to show the started state of not just the server, but also each and every loaded webapp.